# Oracle data insertion strange behavior. Data is truncating while inserting

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

I am using oracle database as back end of one of my projects.

I have a table which has a `ADDRESS_TYPE` column `nvarchar(3)`

In some scenarios the system trying to insert a text  'Business' into the column `ADDRESS_TYPE`. When I try it from the local it is showing an error like the value is too large for the column, this one is an expected result. But the same code I have deployed in `QA` and `Production` but in both cases the data got inserted as `'Bus'` so the text `'Business'` got truncated and it only inserts `'Bus'`. My local instance and the QA instance pointing to the same Database.

```
var data= new MYTABLE();
 data.ADDRESS_TYPE= 'Business';
 context.MYTABLE.AddObject(data);
 context.SaveChanges();
```

Note : I am using Entity framework.

I have tried to insert/update the data directly into the database and I am getting the error value is too large for column. This behavior only happen in the hosted sites. I am planning to put a `log` on the code for getting more idea , but before that I thought of asking here , so if anyone faced the same situation then they might can help me I guess.

I have tried to do the same operation locally using `release` mode there also getting the exception

Anyone have any idea/suggestions so that I can investigate on that way.